# Circle with negative radius?

Tags: graphics, bugs, geometry

**Bug introduced in 9.0 or earlier and fixed in 11.0.0**

---

Why does this work:

```
Graphics[{Circle[{0, 0}, -Pi/4]}]
```

But this doesn't?

```
Graphics[{Circle[{0, 0}, N[-Pi/4]]}]
```

Telling me:

> Radius -0.78539816339744828 should be a positive number or pair of positive numbers, or a Scaled or Offset form.

The radius is negative in both forms.

???

Comment: Perhaps, a bug?

Comment: Interestingly this works `Graphics[Circle[{0, 0}, {-Pi/4, N[- Pi/4]}]]` but only when one of axis is not numerical.

Comment: `Graphics[{Circle[{0, 0}, -1/3 Pi]}]` works, `Graphics[{Circle[{0, 0}, -1/Pi Pi]}]` booms, I'm calling bug (both should fail, IMO).

Comment: All, I'll do a feedback report.

Comment: It is almost like they test the radius input with something like `OrderedQ[Flatten[Join[{0},{r}]]]` which tests for positivity of both the single number r and the two number version in one test, but which will fail for exact expressions like -Pi/4 and negative radicals.

Comment: Everybody knows [this](https://i.imgur.com/pxmKXHX.jpg) is the proper way to test for positivity.

Comment: It works even with rationals: Graphics[{Circle[{0, 0}, -1/2]}]

Comment: In *Mathematica 11* neither version of the code works, so the issue (i.e. the discrepancy) seems to have been resolved I think.